# WP User Query with Custom Fields and Search Results

Tags: wp-query, database, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta

I'm attempting to run a search that sorts through a user profile with Advanced Custom Fields attached. I'm using the WP user query. One of my fields I'm searching against is a repeater field (business_information) and its subfields (business_name).

I'm using the information provided on this [ACF documentation page, #4 Sub Custom Field Values](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)

So, with my variables, it looks like this:

```
    function my_posts_where( $where ) {

        $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'business_information_%", "meta_key LIKE 'business_information_%", $where);

        return $where;
    }

    add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');

    if( !empty( $_GET['usersearch'] ) ){
        $usersearch = stripslashes( trim($_GET['usersearch']) );
        // WP_User_Query arguments
        $args = array(
            'role'           => 'Subscriber',
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                        'key'     => 'membership_class',
                        'value'   => 'Full',
                        'compare' => '=',
                        'type'    => 'CHAR',
                    ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $usersearch,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'last_name',
                        'value'   => $usersearch,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'personal_city',
                        'value'   => $usersearch,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'type'    => 'CHAR',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'personal_province',
                        'value'   => $usersearch,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'type'    => 'CHAR',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'treatments',
                        'value'     => $usersearch,
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',

                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'business_information_%_business_name',
                        'value'     => $usersearch,
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',

                    ),


                ),

            ),
        );
```

The request output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id )  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt2.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
  ( 
    ( 
      ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'membership_class' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'Full' ) 
      AND 
      ( 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'first_name' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' ) 
        OR 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'last_name' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' ) 
        OR 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'personal_city' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' ) 
        OR 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'personal_province' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' ) 
        OR 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'treatments' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' ) 
        OR 
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'business_information_%_business_name' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%name%' )
      )
    ) 
    AND 
    ( 
      ( 
        ( mt2.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '%\"Subscriber\"%' )
      )
    )
  )
) ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

Now, I'll be the first to admit I don't know what the hell I'm doing, but the rest of the searches are working exactly as I want. It's just the business repeater field that's not getting into the search query properly. From what I understand, the above function is supposed to be replacing that piece of the db request, but it's not doing that, and I've got NO idea why or how to make it work, or what it's supposed to actually look like in the end. I've been up and down google on this and just can't find an answer. Everything seems related to posts, not users, and I'm wondering if that's my hangup? Does anyone know anything that can help?

Comment: The ACF folks can probably answer this for you better than we can. :)

Comment: I'm going to make a quick guess that the problem is that your `my_posts_where()` function is adding a filter to `posts_where` which looks to like it may be a hook for `WP_Query` and not for `WP_Users_Query`

Comment: I suspect the same, but I can't find any sort of equivilant or way to connect it to the user query, hence the asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found the answer, but just in case, I just did :)

There's a hook I (finally!) found that lets you do this and works in a similar way to `posts_where`. The hook is `pre_user_query`. Here's an example on the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/#user-contributed-notes

With the above, your function could now look like this:

```
function user_posts_where( $user_query ) {

    $user_query->query_where = str_replace("meta_key = 'business_information_$", "meta_key LIKE 'business_information_%", $user_query->query_where);

    return $user_query;

}

add_filter('pre_user_query', 'user_posts_where');
```

Please note that ACF now recommends using the dollar sign as the wildcard, hence `business_information_$`.

You'd also need to change your `meta_query` to the below, using `business_information_$_business_name` instead:

```
array(
    'key'       => 'business_information_$_business_name',
    'value'     => $usersearch,
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
)
```

Comment: I'm about 2 years away from the project so not in a position to test, but I'm glad to hear there's a hook for this now!